# Nested full-height CSS flexbox columns, scrolling behavior

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to create a full-height layout where only the bottom "part" of the layout scrolls. That is, a couple fixed title bars and then the whole area below scrolls.

Could be done with tables or absolute positioning, but seems like flexbox is the modern answer. And it seems to work fine with a flat column flexbox with three divs and `flex: 1; overflow: auto` in the last div. But not when flexboxes are nested. When I use nested flexboxes, I always get a scrollbar on the whole page, never a scrollbar in the main content area.

This flat flexbox layout works as intended:

```
outer
    b1
    b2
    b3
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.outer {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.b1 {
  background: lightblue;
}

.b2 {
  background: pink;
}

.b3 {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='b1'>
    b1
  </div>
  <div class='b2'>
    b2
  </div>
  <div class='b3'>
    b3<br/> b3
    <br/> b3
    <br/> b3
    <br/> b3
    <br/> b3
    <br/> b3
    <br/> b3
    <br/> b3
    <br/> b3
    <br/> b3
    <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

This nested structure doesn't work as intended:

```
outer
    a1
    a2
        b1
        b2
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.outer {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.a1 {
  background: lightblue;
}

.a2 {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.b1 {
  background: pink;
}

.b2 {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='a1'>
    a1
  </div>
  <div class='a2'>
    <div class='b1'>
      b1
    </div>
    <div class='b2'>
      b2<br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your b2 is doing exactly what you want, it's just flowing out of the bottom of a2. Add `overflow: hidden` to a2 to stop this behaviour:

```css
.a2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.outer {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.a1 {
  background: lightblue;
}

.a2 {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.b1 {
  background: pink;
}

.b2 {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='a1'>
    a1
  </div>
  <div class='a2'>
    <div class='b1'>
      b1
    </div>
    <div class='b2'>
      b2<br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/> b2
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Automatically sizing to the content is exactly what I want - for the title sections. And "expand the last section to consume the rest of the space" seems to be exactly what `flex-grow` is for, right? It seems like I want flexbox behavior and not grid behavior.

Comment: If the last section expands to consume the rest of the space it will never scroll

Comment: Run the code snippet in the question for the flat flexbox "works as intended". The content within the last box scrolls because it has `overflow:auto`.  This is the behavior I'm trying to reproduce, but with nesting instead of a flat structure.

Comment: Thanks, `overflow: hidden` is the magic trick! I have to admit that I don't completely understand why it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to add a fixed position to your example above and ended up with the result below. Only some css code was edited.

```
...

.a1 {
  background: lightblue;
  position : fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

...

.b1 {
  background: pink;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
}
```

[See the full code at codepen.io here.](https://codepen.io/MKebsi/pen/VwBaqYG)

Comment: Thanks, but fixed positioning has all sorts of other behaviors that I do not want, especially with regard to scrolling (for example, the scroll area is the whole page and not just the internal component). It seems like flexbox was designed for this use case, I am just having a hard time figuring out how to make it work.